# how to convert "0.5" number knowing decimals to a valid bignumber

Tags: web3js, bignumber

I am trying to create a transaction where the users sends "0.5" USDT token to a smart contract. My issue is that i can't convert "0.5" to a BigNumber in order to pass it in the transaction using `web3` contract methods as BigNumber.js doesn't accept decimals.
for example this method will throw an error saying that bigNumber doesn't support decimals.

```
Contract.method(web3.utils.toBN("0.5")).send()
```

I can use the `toWei` method of web3 but it doesn't work if the decimals are not equal to 18. How can i do this ? is there a workaround ?

Comment: 0.5 * 10^decimal or should I go better sleep?

Comment: if it was another decimal number wouldn't that result in an error from the JS Number object ?

Comment: Yes You need to use the BN library to power, multiply and div.

Comment: I can try it tomorrow for u . It is 22:44 my time

Comment: Did you try something that supports arbitrary decimals like https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js? It is bad having two libraries for handling arbitrary length numbers, but probably unavoidable in javascript yet.

Answer (score 1):

That is usually how I calculate half of a token. but I don't guarantee that it works correctly :) so please check the code and make sure it works and is correct and use it only on your own responsibility. Web3js (I'm using "web3": "^1.6.0") use this https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/ for BigNumbers

```js
function getHalfCoin() {
    const decimal = 6; // you can get it from the contract;
    var BN = web3.utils.BN;
    const decimalAsBigNumber = new BN(decimal);
    console.log(decimalAsBigNumber); // BN { negative: 0, words: [ 6 ], length: 1, red: null }

    const numberOneAsBigNumber = new BN(1);
    const numberTowAsBigNumber = new BN(2);
    const numberTenAsBigNumber = new BN(10);

    const oneCoin = numberOneAsBigNumber.mul(numberTenAsBigNumber.pow(decimalAsBigNumber));
    console.log(oneCoin); // BN { negative: 0, words: [ 1000000, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null}
    console.log(oneCoin.toString()); // 1000000

    const halfCoin = oneCoin.div(numberTowAsBigNumber);
    console.log(halfCoin); // BN { negative: 0, words: [ 500000 ], length: 1, red: null }
    console.log(halfCoin.toString()); // 500000
}
```

https://bybit-exchange.github.io/erc20-faucet/

here mint 1 token on rinkeby
[image]

and here transfer 0.5 on rinkeby
[image]

Comment: Your solution is not a bad one but using Big.js like Ismael mentioned was much easier and i suggest you do that also.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime  but u can’t do Contract.method(new Big(0.5)).send(), can u?

Comment: I use something like this, Contract.method(web3.utils.toBN(Big(0.5).mul(decimals))).send(). My issue was to multiply the O.5 with the 10^decimals since that is not taken into consideration by the utils.toBN function.

Comment: ah cool nice, add it maybe as answer and accept it , much easier than mine @KakiMasterOfTime